# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

Well the title says it all. I'm not sure why it doesn't want to work.

This is in an AsyncWorker so that might be the issue. Also the variables are outside of a protected method but the same happens when inside.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    ListView workersList = (ListView)findViewById (R.id.workers_list);
    ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();


    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
```

Then later on

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
```

Comment: You need to add a context to the constructor. This answer is extremely easily found if you just looked at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the [`context` parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29). Change to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<ActivityName>.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
```

where replace `<ActivityName>` with the name of your activity class.

Comment: Ok so if my activity is named MainActivity it would be ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation on ArrayAdapter. It doesn't have a constructor with parameters (int, ArrayList). If you prepend context as well then you'll have a constructor that exists.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<ActivityName>.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a context to match the parameters required.

Change your code:
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);

To

Define your context,

Context context;
ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
.
.
.
And when setting your adapter, 
 mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

Hope this helps.. :)